# Regex NOT operator doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to filter files in a folder. I need the files that don't end with ".xml-test". The following regex works as expected (ok1,ok2,ok3 = false, ok4 = true)

```
String regex = ".+\\.xml\\-test$";
boolean ok1 = Pattern.matches(regex, "database123.xml");
boolean ok2 = Pattern.matches(regex, "database123.sql");
boolean ok3 = Pattern.matches(regex, "log_file012.txt");
boolean ok4 = Pattern.matches(regex, "database.xml-test");
```

Now I just need to negate it, but it doesn't work for some reason:

```
String regex = "^(.+\\.xml\\-test)$";
```

I still get ok1,ok2,ok3 = false, ok4 = true

Any ideas? (As people pointed, this could be done easily without regex. But for arguments sake assume I have to use a single regex pattern and nothing else (ie !Pattern.matches(..); is also not allowed))

Comment: Why did you think that would negate it? (I think you're mistaking `[^stuff]` for `^stuff$`

Comment: There is no need to use regex for this..

Comment: [^] means negation, only ^ means begin of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Java regex asserts that a string does NOT end with: `.xml-test`:

```java
String regex = "^(?:(?!\\.xml-test$).)*$";
```

This regex walks the string one character at a time and asserts that at each and every position the remainder of the string is not `.xml-test`.

Simple!

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for:

```
if (! someString.endsWith(".xml-test")) {
  ...
}
```

No regular expression required. Throw this into a [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) as follows:

```
public accept(File dir, String name) {
  return ! name.endsWith(".xml-test");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still I was wondering how can I do this with regex. Do you know what my regex should be?

Comment: On the basis that you would negate the match, you can search for `!Pattern.matches(".+\.xml-test", someString);`

Comment: I cannot do that, it's a 3rd party library function, gets a regex pattern as argument and returns a list.(it's a bit more complex situation than i posted here)

Comment: @Caner: regular expression libraries usually don't support negation as (1) it's extremely expensive, taking exponential time to compile the regex and (2) it interferes with things like capturing and non-regular extensions such as backreferences.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of `^` changes depending on its position in the regexp. When the symbol is inside a character class `[]` as the first character, it means negation of the character class; when it is outside a character class, it means the beginning of line.

The easiest way to negate a result of a match is to use a positive pattern in regex, and then to add a `!` on the Java side to do the negation, like this:

```
boolean isGoodFile = !Pattern.matches(regex, "database123.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, but still I was wondering how can I do this with regex. Do you know what my regex should be?

Comment: @Caner The closest I was able to get to what you are looking for is this expression: `"[^.]+\\.(?!xml-test).*"`. Here is my [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/S84hZy). However, this will give you some "false negatives" when a string would be disqualified because it has `".xml-test"` somewhere in the middle. It passes your tests, though.

Comment: ok, I managed to get your version working(changed to this "[^.]+\\.(?!xml-test$).*"), http://ideone.com/YuhPr0

Answer (score 1):

^ - is not a negation in regexp, this is a symbol indicating beginning of line
you probably need (?!X) X, via zero-width negative lookahead

But I suggest you to use File#listFiles method with FilenameFilter implementation:
name.endsWith(".xml-test")

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to test it with regex, then you should use negative lookbehinds from [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class:

```
String reges = "^.*(?<!\\.xml-test)$"
```

How it works:

1. first you match whole string: from start (^) all characters (.*),
2. you check if what have already matched doesn't have ".xml-test" at end (lookbehind at position you already matched),
3. you test if it's end of string.

Comment: This one returns true for all :(